# The method OnSelectedIndexChanged is not accessed on changing selection in dropdown list.How do i fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the `dropdown` list

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="select_type" runat="server"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="select_type_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and this is the method. On selecting it the method is not getting entered.

```
protected void select_type_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (select_type.Text != "Select Type")
     {
          string city = select_type.Text;
          if (select_type.Text == "Domestic")
          {
               Data mydataclass = new Data();
               DataSet dr = mydataclass.select(1, city, "");
               ListItem[] lstitem = GetNamesFromDataset(dr, "Packages");
               select_package.Items.AddRange(lstitem);
          }

      }
  }
```

I have added values to the list on `Page_Load`. Here is the method

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         select_type.Items.Insert(0, "Select Type");
         select_type.Items.Insert(1, "Domestic");
         select_type.Items.Insert(2, "International");
     } 
   }
```

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow.. When i wrote the question it was in a proper format. Dono why its come like this.

Comment: you should `bind` the dropdownlist

Comment: @preethamjhingade the above code working perfectly to me. So please give some hint about your page.

Comment: @preethamjhingade is there a lot of controls in your page ??

Comment: yea the page has a lot of controls.Shall i add the entire code?

Answer (score 1):

You should enable `AutoPostBack` property for your `asp:DropDownList` as you did but `select_type_SelectedIndexChanged` is not getting entered, why?
I think because your `asp:ListItem` of that `DropDownList` does not have `Value`
so you should set the `value` of each `ListItem`

for example try this :

```
 <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="select_type" runat="server"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="select_type_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="val1">Item1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="val2">item2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and based on your question I can't see `asp:ListItem` in other words you shoud `bind` your `DropDown` or add `ListItem` manually or programmatically.

If you add them in code-behind it's better to do that in `if(!IsPostBack)` block like:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            select_type.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item1", "Val1"));
            select_type.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item2", "Val2"));
        }
```

If it doesn't work yet I think you have disabled `ViewStateMode` for page so you can enable it for your `DropDown` I think the issue will be resolved by this.

```
 select_type.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled;
```

Comment: I have added the list items on page load.

Comment: @preethamjhingade Have a look at answer now .

Comment: I have added the items on postback as you have mentioned. The list items are getting displayed but on selection change the method is still not getting entered and i enabled viewstate too .Still it doesn't work.                                 Thanks in advance.

Comment: @preethamjhingade enable it at the page level `<%@ Page Language="C#" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ....`

Answer (score 0):

I had used all the suggestions given by all. The problem was that I had used a button with id="submit". This was preventing any changes. I checked some old questions and got to know this problem is in visual studio since quite a few years or that it has some default script that prevents these changes.